Concentration of measure for $X\cdot \mathrm{sign}(Y)- \mathbb E[X\cdot \mathrm {sign}(Y)]$ with $(X,Y)$ being multivariate Gaussian.
Say we have two $\mathbb R^n$ valued random vectors $X,Y$ such that $\left(\begin{array}\\X\\ Y\end{array}\right)$ is multivariate Gaussian with mean $0$. Given this one could apply similar methods as in Hanson Wright inequality to show an exponential concentration of measure for $X\cdot Y$. My problem is slightly different in that i want to show a concentration for
$$
X\cdot \mathrm {sign}(Y) - \mathbb E[X\cdot \mathrm {sign}(Y)],
$$
where $\mathrm{sign}$ is applied component wise and $\cdot$ denotes the scalar product. Here one loses the affine transformation property of Gaussians that one can exploit in combination with Hanson Wright inequality in the simpler $X\cdot Y$ case.

I am stuck with this problem for a bit now. What i have tried so far is conditioning on $Y$ as the conditional distribution $\mathcal L(X|Y=y)$ is again a multivariate Gaussian and allows exploitation of Gaussian properties. This allows me to concentrate the quantity around $\mathrm {sign}(Y)\mathbb E[X|Y]$ with exponential tail but not around $\mathbb E[\mathrm{sign}(Y)X]$.
It is also possible to use Markov's Inequality/Chebychev Inequality and conditioning on $Y$. Like this i can establish a concentration but this is most certainly suboptimal as one won't archive exponential convergence this way. But it proofs atleast that one can archive some convergence.
Also the special case $X=Y$ corresponds to the case of summing up an absolute normal distribution so results in this direction might also be of interest.
The way that Hanson Wright inequality can be applied to $X\cdot Y$ is the following: We have
$$
2X\cdot Y = \left(\begin{array}\\X\\ Y\end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}\\Y\\ X\end{array}\right).
$$
Now let $\Sigma$ be the covariance matrix of $X,Y$ then $\left(\begin{array}\\X\\ Y\end{array}\right)= \sqrt{\Sigma}Z$, where $Z$ is standard normal and for a permutation matrix $P$ we have $\left(\begin{array}\\Y\\ X\end{array}\right)=P\left(\begin{array}\\X\\ Y\end{array}\right)$. Then we have
$$
2X\cdot Y = Z^T \sqrt{\Sigma}^TP\sqrt{\Sigma}Z.
$$
and so Hanson Wright applies here and gives a bound
$$
\mathbb P(|X\cdot Y - \mathbb E[X\cdot Y]| >t)\le \exp\left[-c\min\left\{\frac{t^2}{\|\sqrt{\Sigma}^TP\sqrt{\Sigma}\|_F^2},\frac{t}{\|\sqrt{\Sigma}^TP\sqrt{\Sigma}\|_{\mathrm{op}}}\right\}\right]
$$
for some absolute constant $c>0$.

do you know anything about the correlation(s) between $X$ and $Y$?

@Quertiopler Since the expression is invariant under scaling of $Y$ lets assume W.l.o.g. that $\Sigma_{YY}$, the correlation of $Y$ with itself has a diagonal of $1$. Furthermore lets assume that $\Sigma$ the correlation matrix of $X,Y$ has the property $|\Sigma|_{\mathrm{op}}=1/n$. I would prefer to not assume more if possible.

Setting $$Z=X-\frac{\mathbf{Cov}(Y,X)}{\mathbf{Var}(Y)}Y,$$ we know that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent gaussian vectors with mean zero. Then $$X\cdot\operatorname{sign}(Y)=Z\cdot\operatorname{sign}(Y) + \frac{\mathbf{Cov}(Y,X)}{\mathbf{Var}(Y)}|Y|_1.$$ I think this decomposition, together with the union bound will produce a concentration bound.

@Sangchu Lee Thats a great idea thank you. I didn't see that one yet and this looks promising to me.

@Sangchu Lee I just calculated everything through and if $Cov(Y,X)$ denotes the covariance matrix then this is wrong. We would get the decomposition
$$
X\cdot \mathrm{sign}(Y) = Z\cdot \mathrm{sign}(Y) + Y^T\frac{\mathbf{Cov}(Y,X)}{\mathbf {Var}(Y)} \mathrm{sign}(Y)
$$
which is exactly the conditional expectation given $Y$ on the rhs. Anyway if this is ment as a diag. matrix with $\frac{\mathbf{Cov}(Y_i,X_i)}{\mathbf{Var}(Y_i)}$ on its diagonal this works. The union bound however is suboptimal if concentrating around the expectation. I edited the question to make it cleared in that regard.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions
For multivariate Gaussian we have similar result: $Y$ and $X - \Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}Y$ are independent, where the covariance matrix of $(X, Y)$ is partitioned as $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_{XX} & \Sigma_{XY} \ \Sigma_{YX} & \Sigma_{YY} \end{bmatrix}$

@BGM Yeah thats in parts what i ment. If we make $Z$ and $Y$ independent through $Z= X-\Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}Y$ we get
$$
X\cdot \mathrm{sign}(Y) = Z\cdot \mathrm{sign}(Y) + Y^T \Sigma_{YX}\Sigma^{-1}_{YY} \mathrm{sign}(Y)
$$
but unfortunately we do not get $|Y|_1$ which might be easier to handle. In that case it indeed holds that $Z$ and $Y$ are independent though, which would not hold if we only wipe out the diagonal the way i mentioned before.

Oops, you are right. I was treating $X$ and $Y$ like they are univariate. Apologies!
